# setState vs StreamProvider

Tags: flutter, location, provider

I'm a Flutter newbie and I have a basic understanding question:

I built a google_maps widget where I get the location of the user and also would like to show the current location in a TextWidget.

So I'm calling a function in initState querying the stream of the geolocator package:

```
class _SimpleMapState extends State<SimpleMap> {
  Position userPosStreamOutput;

  void initPos() async {
    userPosStream = geoService.getStreamLocation();
    userPosStream.listen((event) {
      print('event:$event');
      setState(() {
        userPosStreamOutput = event;
      });
    });
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    initPos();
    super.initState();
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    return Scaffold( //(very simplified)
      body: Text(userPosStreamOutput.toString()),
```

This works just fine. But would it make sense to use a Streamprovider instead? Why?

Thanks
Joerg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An advantage to use StreamProvider is to optimize the process of re-rendering. As setState is called to update userPosStreamOutput value, the build method will be called each time your stream yields an event.

With a StreamProvider, you can apply the same logic of initializing a stream but then, you will use a Consumer which will listen to new events incoming and provide updated data to children widgets without triggering other build method calls.

Using this approach, the build method will be called once and it also makes code more readable in my opinion.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: StreamProvider(
      create: (_) => geoService.getStreamLocation(),
      initialData: null,
      child: Consumer<Position>(
        builder: (context, userPosStreamOutput, _) {
          return Text(userPosStreamOutput.toString());
        },
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```